# Stange value being returned from a function ( using popcorn.js, angular, and jade )

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, pug

thanks for reading.

I have a "strange" problem. I am running Angular and Jade together ( on a node server ) and have implemented popcorn.js ( an html5 media framework, popcornjs.com ).

There is an event property on Popcorn called currentTime(), so when you call Popcorn.currentTime(), it gives you the current time of the video that it is playing. This functionality is working in a console.log(Popcorn.currentTime()); but for some reason when I try to get that same value out of the function, I get a value of '9'.

I'll list my Angular Controller, and my Jade Code. My question lies in the //Show current time section  :

Here is my Angular Controller :

```
  angular.module('app').controller('mvEditCtrl', function ($scope,     mvNotifier,mvIdentity,$location){ 

 $scope.identity = mvIdentity;   
 $scope.videoID = $location.search().id;

})
  //This custom directive holds the loading of the Popcorn video to avoid race condition. 
  .directive('popcornVideo', ['$timeout', function (timer) {
    return {
        scope: false,
        link: function ($scope) {
          timer(function () {
            var video = Popcorn.smart(
             '#video',
             $scope.videoID);

            //>>****Show current time. 
            $scope.theTime = setInterval(function() { 
              video.currentTime();
              console.log(video.currentTime());
              var time = video.currentTime();
              return time;
            },1000);

          }, 0);
        }
    }
}]);
```

And here is my Jade Code ( see where I call {{theTime}} ). It's worth noting I have tried to use ng-bind here as well with the same reusult in the Dom ( 9 ) .

```
.panel.panel-primary
.panel-heading.text-center Video Preview
.panel-body
        .popcornVideo(popcorn-video)
            #video(controls)
            #footnotediv
.panel.panel-primary
    .panel-heading.text.center Video Controls
    .panel-body.text-center Video Timer :  {{theTime}}
```

SO in recap, {{theTime}} is rendering on the page as "9", and console.log is showing the current video time ( 2:34) etc...

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setInterval()` returns an id of the timer so you can clear it later. Try this instead (using the `$interval` service so angular knows when `theTime` updates...

```
.directive('popcornVideo', ['$interval', function ($interval) {
    return {
        scope: false,
        link: function ($scope) {
            var video = Popcorn.smart(
                '#video',
                $scope.videoID);

            //>>****Show current time. 
            $interval(function() { 
                $scope.theTime = video.currentTime();
            },1000);
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Hi Anthony - That worked for me - thanks very much. Also interesting lesson about where the 9 was coming from. I really couldn't figure it out. Thanks! Jesse